# Join and Group By in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

#### DB overview

I have two collections - first with the employees details and the second with their membership to the certain departments.

`Emps` collection sample (of size of about 331.5k documents):

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dc027718da295b969e529ae"), 
    "emp_no" : 10001, 
    ...,
    "gender" : "M", 
    "titles" : [
        {
            "title" : "Senior Engineer", 
            "dept_name" : "Development", 
            "from_date" : "1986-06-26", 
            "to_date" : "9999-01-01"
        },
        {
            "title" : "Staff", 
            "dept_name" : "Human Resources", 
            "from_date" : "1986-06-26", 
            "to_date" : "9999-01-01"
        }
    ]
}
```

`departments` collection sample (of size of about 300k documents):

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dc026438da295b969e01893"), 
    "dept_no" : "d005", 
    "dept_name" : "Development", 
    "emp_no" : 10001, 
    "from_date" : "1986-06-26", 
    "to_date" : "9999-01-01"
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dc026438da295b969e01894"), 
    "dept_no" : "d003", 
    "dept_name" : "Human Resources", 
    "emp_no" : 10001, 
    "from_date" : "1986-06-26", 
    "to_date" : "9999-01-01"
}
```

#### The question

Now **how do I count how many employees with `gender` equal to `M` are working in each department?** I came up with this query so far:

```
db.getCollection("emps").aggregate([
    {$match: {'gender': 'F'}},
    {$project: {_id: 0, emp_no: 1, gender: 1}},
    {$lookup: {
        from: 'departments',
        localField: 'emp_no',
        foreignField: 'emp_no',
        as: 'departments',
    }},
])
```

But it lacks the key stages, like

- the condition about `to_date` as `"9999-01-01"` means that the employee is still working in the department,
- grouping by the department name

I'd like the query to be as efficient as it possibly could be, so with that said I try to avoid using `$unwind` as it produces more documents. Is there any other way to reach inner array elements without `$unwind` stage?

One last thing - I saw that it's possible to use a pipeline inside the `$lookup` so I could get rid of fields that I'm not interested in by making projection on the looked-up documents, but I didn't manage to do it properly by myself. If you know how to do this, please let me know.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way avoiding `$unwind` by starting with the employee collection, I still wouldn't say this is a deal breaker in the pipeline efficiency wise.

However by starting the pipeline from the `departments` collection you can avoid it, Also heuristically (assuming the company is large and been around a while) you can eliminate more people by first matching who's still working in the company (by matching `to_date` on the department collection first) than you can by matching gender first.  ( gender eliminates 50%, while active employees could be much lower like `10%`). You can actually calculate the distributions yourself and decide which "way" of the pipeline is more efficient for you.

I'm just bringing this up as the most expensive stage in the pipeline is the `$lookup`, this is the action that affects performance the most. Hence the smaller the `$lookup` the better the overall performance will be.

Here is how I would do this:

```
db.departments.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "to_date": "9999-01-01"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "emps",
      let: {
        empNum: "$emp_no"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$gender",
                    "M"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$empNum",
                    "$emp_no"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "employees"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "employees.0": {
        $exists: true
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$dept_no",
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NFXZKU-HCJl)

As I feel the question core was more about performance than capabilities I will add these couple of tips:

1. You would want to make sure you have an `index` built on both the `to_date` field in the department collection and the `gender`/`emp_no` on the emps field.
2. Consider creating a new `boolean` field like `stillEmployedHere` and update it only on current employee's, with a spare index it will be much faster than the `to_date` query. This tip specifically is only for large scale as it will have minor affects otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! However, I encountered the problem with it - the aggregation with first two stages lasts for more than a minute, and if I add another `$match` it didn't stopped in 5 minutes and would possibly last even longer... Is this expected behaviour while the `departments` collection has about 331.5k documents and the `emps` has about 300k? Maybe there's something missing in the query that unintentionally make it last "forever"? There are no indexes added yet.

Comment: Especially if the fields i mentioned are indexed it shouldn't take this long, the scale your describing is somewhat "small". are there any relevant hardware issue's possible? small cpu /RAM or cpu and memory being used by other programs?

Comment: rather no, I checked it out just now. I have 2gb of ram on my vps and it's usage is on the 10% level, the cpu is even less (2%).